# parse JSON containing 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

My ajax call returns data like this:

```
{"result":[{"stats":{"min":{"caller_id.name":"Person1"},"count":"5"},"groupby_fields":[{"field":"caller_id","value":"ce4ddid73hes6e806d7070e21f961987"}]},{"stats":{"min":{"caller_id.name":"Person2"},"count":"2"},"groupby_fields":[{"field":"caller_id","value":"36ffbcfedbf9ba406d7070e21f96199c"}]},{"stats":{"min":{"caller_id.name":"Person3"},"count":"1"},"groupby_fields":[{"field":"caller_id","value":"714dd540dbefbe806d7070e21f96196a"}]},{"stats":{"min":{"caller_id.name":"Person4"},"count":"1"},"groupby_fields":[{"field":"caller_id","value":"ce4dd540dbefbe806d7070e21f961987"}]}]}
```

I then use `var json = $.parseJSON(data);` and get this (from the console log):

> ```
> {result: Array(4)}
> result:Array(4)
> 0:groupby_fields:Array(1)
> 0:{field: "caller_id", value: "ce4ddid73hes6e806d7070e21f961987"}
> length:1
> __proto__:Array(0)
> stats:count:"5"
> min:{caller_id.name: "Person1"}
> __proto__:Object
> __proto__:Object
> 1:{stats: {…}, groupby_fields: Array(1)}
> 2:{stats: {…}, groupby_fields: Array(1)}
> 3:{stats: {…}, groupby_fields: Array(1)}
> length:4
> __proto__:Array(0)
> __proto__:Object
> ```

In previous calls I loop through the data to pull the values using something like this

```
var callerName = json[i]["caller_id.name"];
```

I'm not sure how to do it in this scenario.

I tried a few variations of the line above but didn't have any success.

I need to get the `caller_id`, `count`, and `caller_id.name`.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of structures in JSON: arrays `[value1, value2]` and objects `{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}`.

In Javascript, you access:

- array elements via `array[index]`.
- object properties via `object.property` or `object['property']`. The latter is required if the property name includes special characters.

You can chain these, so for instance you could write:

- `json.result[0].stats.min['caller_id.name']`
- `json.result[0].stats.count`
- `json.result[0].groupby_fields[0].field`
- `json.result[0].groupby_fields[0].value`

and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the syntax for getting the results.

Answer (score 0):

This should't be difficult. Assuming the value of `i` is `0`, here is the way by which you can get corresponding values:

```js
let data = {
  "result": [{
    "stats": {
      "min": {
        "caller_id.name": "Person1"
      },
      "count": "5"
    },
    "groupby_fields": [{
      "field": "caller_id",
      "value": "ce4ddid73hes6e806d7070e21f961987"
    }]
  }, {
    "stats": {
      "min": {
        "caller_id.name": "Person2"
      },
      "count": "2"
    },
    "groupby_fields": [{
      "field": "caller_id",
      "value": "36ffbcfedbf9ba406d7070e21f96199c"
    }]
  }, {
    "stats": {
      "min": {
        "caller_id.name": "Person3"
      },
      "count": "1"
    },
    "groupby_fields": [{
      "field": "caller_id",
      "value": "714dd540dbefbe806d7070e21f96196a"
    }]
  }, {
    "stats": {
      "min": {
        "caller_id.name": "Person4"
      },
      "count": "1"
    },
    "groupby_fields": [{
      "field": "caller_id",
      "value": "ce4dd540dbefbe806d7070e21f961987"
    }]
  }]
};

let i = 0;
console.log(data.result[i].stats.min['caller_id.name']);
console.log(data.result[i].stats.count);
console.log(data.result[i].groupby_fields[0].value);
```

I hope you can loop through `data.result` using a loop and provide specific values of `i` to the expressions.

Answer (score 0):

To get the 'caller_id.name' key use

```
var json = {"result":[{"stats":{"min":{"caller_id.name":"Person1"},"count":"5"},"groupby_fields":[{"field":"caller_id","value":"ce4ddid73hes6e806d7070e21f961987"}]},{"stats":{"min":{"caller_id.name":"Person2"},"count":"2"},"groupby_fields":[{"field":"caller_id","value":"36ffbcfedbf9ba406d7070e21f96199c"}]},{"stats":{"min":{"caller_id.name":"Person3"},"count":"1"},"groupby_fields":[{"field":"caller_id","value":"714dd540dbefbe806d7070e21f96196a"}]},{"stats":{"min":{"caller_id.name":"Person4"},"count":"1"},"groupby_fields":[{"field":"caller_id","value":"ce4dd540dbefbe806d7070e21f961987"}]}]}

//json['result'][0]["stats"]["min"]['caller_id.name']

for (x in json['result']){ console.log(r['result'][x]["stats"]["min"]['caller_id.name'])}
```

result:

```
"Person1"
"Person2"
"Person3"
"Person4"
```